# HTML entity with translation in hyperlink

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Look the following code:

```
= link_to t('view.buy.body.buying_wizard_tile.text'), '/buy/wizard'
```

So far, so good.

The problem is: **I need to concatenate the translation with the `&raquo;` HTML entity**.

### What I already tried

```
# The following just shows "&raquo;" instead of the entity itself.
= link_to t('view.buy.body.buying_wizard_tile.text') + '&raquo;', '/buy/wizard'

# The following just shows the same thing as before.
= link_to t('view.buy.body.buying_wizard_tile.text') + '&raquo;'.html_safe, '/buy/wizard'
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch, have you tried

```
link_to (t('view.buy.body.buying_wizard_tile.text') + '&raquo;').html_safe, '/buy/wizard'
```

Comment: Yeah I think this is due to the way html_safe works when concatenating strings, if one of them is unsafe, then the result will be unsafe. I couldn't find a reference though.